# get list from table used to create "filter button"

Tags: php, html, sql, filter

This must be something trivial but long to explain. I cannot form good question for google. I dont know if I should get this result in SQL query or I need to change PHP part which includes sql query. (My knowledge is small, I am making my own very simple planner website but im stuck on creating button for filtering options.)

Imagine I have table named “Records” with 3 columns “ID, Item, Category”.
In categories I write all data in CAPITAL LETTERS and categories can be repeating.

So example table Records looks like this(in columns layout like this: id-item-CATEGORY):

> 1-sleep-HEALTH
>  2-ate breakfast-FOOD&DRINK
>  3-drank
>   coffee-FOOD&DRINK
>  4-took eyedrops-HEALTH
>  5-tram to
>   work-TRAVEL

I know how to list all data from column Category, but I want to avoid repeating categories. I need to get list of categories like this (Health and Food&drink does not duplicate):

> HEALTH
>  FOOD&DRINK
>  TRAVEL

So with this list I can than via php generate html select tag options.
In php part I would use something like this:

```
$query1=mysqli_query($db,"select * from Records asc”);
while($query2=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
echo “<option value=“.$query2[‘category_option’].”>”.$query2[‘category_option’].”</option>”
};
```

So the result HTML will look something like this.

```
<select>
  <option value="HEALTH">HEALTH</option>
  <option value="FOOD&DRINK">FOOD&DRINK</option>
  <option value="TRAVEL">TRAVEL</option>
</select>
```

Can you please point me right direction? Or mention some best practice to reach this kind of functionality. Thanks to all which try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` in your SQL:

`SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM Records`

No duplicates will be returned.

Have a play with it on this link https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp

Note that now we are only fetching one column here instead of `*`.

You can also use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM Records GROUP BY Category
```

https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Just remember that `DISTINCT` applies to the full row; that is, to the combination of columns you specify. Doesn't affect here since there's a single column, but you might take that into consideration if you start adding more columns.

Comment: Yes I was just editing to add `GROUP BY` as well :-P

Comment: Oh perfect @delboy1978uk , `DISTINCT` fits for my button perfectly, and its good to know about `GROUP BY` as well. Thanks a lot